# Joining two large tables (SQL)

Tags: sql

I am joining two large tables

The number of rows in tables are :

> root@server1:~# /a/bin/sql2 "select paramName, value from RA_ResourceThresholds" | wc -l
>   69304
>
> root@server1:~# /a/bin/sql2 "select regionID, resourceID from
>   RA_RegionInfo" | wc -l 28867

However, when I am trying to join them, I am getting the error from query about an intermediate data set being too large. Can anyone tell me a workaround this?

> root@server1:~# /a/bin/sql2 "SELECT ri.regionID, ri.resourceID,
>   rt.paramName, rt.value FROM RA_RegionInfo ri, RA_ResourceThresholds rt
>   WHERE ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset"
>   error: resource limit exceeded: intermediate table size (limit 3000000
>   rows)

Comment: Try join: `SELECT ri.regionID, ri.resourceID, rt.paramName, rt.value FROM RA_RegionInfo ri join RA_ResourceThresholds rt ON ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset`

Comment: mysql or sql-server .. remove the unuseful flag please

Comment: Please tag properly.  `mysql` is not `sql-server`

Comment: Hm, three million rows are a small limit for an intermediate result, given that many people don't consider a *single table* of three million records a big table. Anyway, how many matches do you expect? When all records have distinct regionID and resourceID, then you'd get 69304 rows, when all have the same regionID and resourceID, you'd get 2 billion rows. Maybe it's just that most records share the same regionID and resourceID and you reach the limit.

Comment: I just googled "resource limit exceeded: intermediate table" and only found one match: this very SO request. Are you sure this is MySQL or SQL Server and not some more rarely used OR mapper or some other software interfering here?

Comment: Whatever `sql2` is...?

Comment: root@23.73.134.125:~# /a/bin/sql2 "SELECT ri.regionID, ri.resourceID, rt.paramName, rt.value FROM RA_RegionInfo ri join RA_ResourceThresholds rt ON ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset"
error: syntax error on line 1 at 'join' @Ambrish

Comment: Yes you are right @ThorstenKettner . Most of them share same resourceID but the regionID are different. 
I am hence searching a way around to this

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Yes this is mysql only. 
I'm not sure what you mean by mapper?

Comment: An OR mapper is software that does the database access when you are only working with objects instead of tables. Can be a real nuisance ;-)

Comment: By the way, you do know that you can get the row count with `count`, yes? E.g. `select count(*) from RA_RegionInfo`. When working with a database, have the DBMS get the data (the amount of records in this case). Don't select more data then needed only to aggregate or filter that outside the database.

Comment: Use `AS` identefier as well: `SELECT ri.regionID, ri.resourceID, rt.paramName, rt.value FROM RA_RegionInfo AS ri join RA_ResourceThresholds AS rt ON ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that many share the same recourceID, but not the regionID. So joining on the combination of the two should not lead to that many records.

Maybe MySQL uses an index on recourceID only to build an intermediate result which it wants to scan for regionID matches. Hence the too many records.

So make sure you have an index on *both* fields in both tables:

```
create index idx_ri_both on RA_RegionInfo(regionID, recourceID);
create index idx_rt_both on RA_ResourceThresholds(regionID, recourceID);
```

This should lead to joining the matching records directly rather than joining more than needed in a first step.

I made regionID the first column in the indexes, because I gather this is the more selective one.

And by the way: the comma-separated join syntax was made redundant in 1992. It should not be used anymore. When interpreted literally this would be a cross join, i.e. two billion rows, that would be filtered by the where clause afterwards. (However, MySQL's optimizer should see through this and apply the join criteria directly.) Use explicit joins instead: `FROM RA_RegionInfo ri JOIN RA_ResourceThresholds rt ON ...`.

And are you sure you really want to join the complete tables without any criteria? Usually such is not necessary, because one would be interested in particular data.

Comment: I have these criterias:

Comment: I have these criteria's:
ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset

also when I am using explicit JOIN, it throws me this error

root@23.73.134.125:~# /a/bin/sql2 "SELECT ri.regionID, ri.resourceID, rt.paramName, rt.value FROM RA_RegionInfo ri JOIN RA_ResourceThresholds rt ON ri.resourceID=rt.resourceID AND ri.regionOffset=rt.regionOffset"
error: syntax error on line 1 at 'JOIN'

Comment: Yes, you do have criteria on how to join records, but no criteria on which particular data to select (say a certain region, country, date, whatever). Your query is perfectly valid in MySQL and almost any other RDBMS. Somehow the errors you are getting don't sound like MySQL at all. But I have no idea what's actually wrong. Is this the MySQL Shell you are using or what else?